# How to validate a null input

Tags: c#, validation

the problem I'm having is to validate the input means putting it in a try catch which then wont pass the variable through and I'm getting this error:

Use of unassigned local variable 'MainMenuSelection'

I've validated using this method before but for some reason it's not working now, please help

```
//Take the menu selection
try
{
    mainMenuSelection = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid selection");
}


switch (mainMenuSelection) //Where error is shown
```

Comment: can you show the definition of mainMenuSelection?

Comment: You really ought not to write `catch` without specifying the exception type.  It's a bad habit that will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously user can input anything which would not be parsed as a single `byte`. Try out using [Byte.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse.aspx) method which does not generate exception and just return status flag.

You can go further and add more analysis for an user input if needed:

```
// Initialize by a default value to avoid
// "Use of unassigned local variable 'MainMenuSelection'" error
byte mainMenuSelection = 0x00;    
string input = Console.ReadLine();

// If acceptable - remove possible spaces at the start and the end of a string
input = input.Trim();
if (input.Lenght > 1)
{
   // can you do anything if user entered multiple characters?
}
else
{
   if (!byte.TryParse(input, out mainMenuSelection))
   {
       // parsing error
   }
   else
   {
       // ok, do switch
   }
}
```

Also perhaps you just need a single character not a byte?
Then just do:

```
// Character with code 0x00 would be a default value. 
// and indicate that nothing was read/parsed    
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char mainMenuSelection = input.Length > 0 ? input[0] : 0x00;
```

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be to use `byte.TryParse()`.  It's made specifically for these types of scenarios.

```
byte b;
if (byte.TryParse("1", out b))
{
    //do something with b
}
else
{
    //can't be parsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just concerned about the input itself, you can use the [Byte.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkktxbeh.aspx) and then handle the false boolean case instead.

```
byte mainMenuSelection;
if (Byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mainMenuSelection)
{
    switch(mainMenuSelection);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid selection");
}
```